# F# syntax for repeated pipelining

Tags: f#

Is there any syntax in F# which allows pipelining by a list of functions in sequence concisely?  For example,

```
    x |> fun1 |> fun2 |> fun3 ...
```

Or is there a design pattern which makes this task unnecessary?  In my case I am making a (naive) Sudoku solver and have a function that looks like this:

```
let reduceByRows poss = 
    poss 
    |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 1) |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 2) |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 3)
    |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 4) |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 5) |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 6)
    |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 7) |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 8) |> reduceBy (rowIndeces 9)
```

Is there any way to clean up something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a fold to me. What about

```
let reduceByRows poss = 
  Seq.fold (fun p i -> reduceBy (rowIndices i) p) poss {1..9}
```

Answer (score 8):

One way to look at this is folding on pipelining operator `|>` instead of folding on data:

```
{1..9} |> Seq.map (rowIndices >> reduceBy)
       |> Seq.fold (|>) poss
```

In general, if `fun1`, `fun2`, etc have the same signature, you can apply `|>` on a sequence of functions i.e. *repeated pipelining*:

```
  [
   fun1; 
   fun2; 
   fun3;
   //...
         ] |> List.fold (|>) x
```